# Pandas - Group each column by itself

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataframe:

```
    col1  col2  col3  col4  
0   True  False True  True
1   True  True  False False 
2   False False True  False 
3   True  True  False True
```

Is there a way to group my data so that I get something like the following where the numbers in the table are counts of occurrences:

```
       col2         col3        col4  
       True False   True False  True False
col1         
True   2    1       x    x      x    x
False  0    1       x    x      x    x
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `col1` to be the index  axis. Perform `stack` operation to reshape it to a long formatted series object.

Groupby levels 0 and 1 of the multiindex-series produced and compute their respective value-counts. Then, `unstack` and sort both the indices row and columnwise, optionally filling `NaNs` with 0.

```
(df.set_index('col1').stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).value_counts().unstack(level=[1,2])
   .sort_index(ascending=False, axis=1).sort_index(ascending=False).fillna(0).astype(int))
```

```
       col4        col3        col2      
      True  False True  False True  False
col1                                     
True      2     1     1     2     2     1
False     0     1     1     0     0     1
```

A further simplified solution per comment by @jezrael:

```
(df.set_index('col1').stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).value_counts()
   .sort_index(ascending=[False, True, False]).unstack([1,2]).fillna(0).astype(int))
```

```
       col2        col3        col4      
      True  False True  False True  False
col1                                     
False     0     1     1     0     0     1
True      2     1     1     2     2     1
```

Additionally, you can sort the index axis in descending order to get back your desired output.

Comment: You can replace `.fillna(0).astype(int)` with `.unstack(..., fill_value=0)`. (That might have been added after this answer was posted.)